# Small python programme taking 15 minutes to run

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So my code works as I expect it to but it's taking 15 minutes to run this section of code. It's the dataframe part of it that the bulk of the time is taken.

I'm new to Python so just wondering how I can make the code more efficient?

I think Its the for loop going through the dataframe? How would I change this to not loop through every iteration and to just perform the calculations on the dataframe items?

​

```
import csv
import requests
import json
import openpyxl
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
import math
import time

start_time = time.time()

postcode_geo = []

with open (r'Desktop\Python Projects\Work - Transport Movement\open_postcode_geo.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        postcode_geo.append(row)

#function to find lat,lon of given postcode
postcode_geo_postcodes = [x[0] for x in postcode_geo]

def FindLL(postcode):
    if postcode in postcode_geo_postcodes:
        for x in range(0,len(postcode_geo)):
            if postcode == postcode_geo[x][0]:
                latitude = postcode_geo[x][7]
                longitude = postcode_geo[x][8]
                return f'{longitude},{latitude}'  
    else:
        print("Postcode can't find longitude/latitude, please check format")

#user inputs start and end postcode
start_postcode = input("Enter start postcode here (with spaces):")
end_postcode = input("Enter end postcode here (with spaces):")

#find lat,lon of postcodes
StartLL = FindLL(start_postcode)
EndLL = FindLL(end_postcode)

print(StartLL)
print(EndLL)

#Get nodes from project osrm API Example = #http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/-0.2507693,51.364718;-0.3795724,51.6110899?alternatives=false&annotations=nodes
route = requests.get(f'http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/{StartLL};{EndLL}?alternatives=false&annotations=nodes')
routejson = route.json()
route_nodes = routejson['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['annotation']['nodes']

print(route_nodes)

#Turn nodes into longitude and latitude
RouteNodeLL = []

for node in route_nodes:
    response_xml = requests.get(f'https://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/node/{node}')
    response_xml_as_string = response_xml.content
    responseXml = ET.fromstring(response_xml_as_string)
    for child in responseXml.iter('node'):
        RouteNodeLL.append((float(child.attrib['lat']), float(child.attrib['lon'])))


#create dataframe of current locations and add columns showing distance from nodes
df = pd.read_excel(r'Desktop\Python Projects\Work - Transport Movement\CurrentYodelTransportLocations.xlsx')

df['Latitude v2'] = df['Latitude v2'].astype(float)

for waypointLat, waypointLong in RouteNodeLL:
    for label, row in df.iterrows():
        df.loc[label,f'Distance From Node - {waypointLat}, {waypointLong}'] = (((math.acos(math.sin((row['Latitude v2']*math.pi/180)) * math.sin((waypointLat*math.pi/180))+math.cos((row['Latitude v2']*math.pi/180)) * math.cos((waypointLat*math.pi/180)) * math.cos(((row['Longitude v2'] - waypointLong )*math.pi/180))))*180/math.pi)*60*1.1515*1.609344)

print(df)

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: Approximately how large are `RouteNodeLL` and `df`?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty inefficient:

```
def FindLL(postcode):
    if postcode in postcode_geo_postcodes:
        for x in range(0,len(postcode_geo)):
            if postcode == postcode_geo[x][0]:
                latitude = postcode_geo[x][7]
                longitude = postcode_geo[x][8]
                return f'{longitude},{latitude}'  
    else:
        print("Postcode can't find longitude/latitude, please check format")
```

You're searching the entire postcode list, and you're doing it the slow way (iterating over the list in Python and checking each item) rather than using `list.index()`. And you're searching an equally long list using `in`, though that's faster because it is all one Python statement.

Instead, use a dictionary. Dictionaries use hashing so they go right to the item you're looking for without a search, which is much faster. For example:

```
postcode_geo = {}

# ...

with open (r'Desktop\Python Projects\Work - Transport Movement\open_postcode_geo.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        postcode_geo[row[0]] = row

# ...

def FindLL(postcode):
    if postcode in postcode_geo:
        latitude = postcode_geo[postcode][7]
        longitude = postcode_geo[postcode][8]
        return f'{longitude},{latitude}'  
    else:
        print("Postcode can't find longitude/latitude, please check format")
```

You could probably do it even faster by reading the postcode geo map into a dataframe and joining it to the other one, but I'm not familiar enough with Pandas to take a stab at that.